# Ui-router configured from multple modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a large angular appso i want to configure ui-router states per module.
I have a main module and 2 sub-modules:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.page1', 'app.page2']).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view>'
  });
});

angular.module('app.page1', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('main.page1', {});
});

angular.module('app.page2', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('main.page2', {})
});


// I want to go from main.page1 to main.page2, so i used 

$state.go('main.page1');
// and
$state.go('^.page1');
```

but it doesn't work!
And as i just want to split the large config file, i tried this [proposition](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/54#issuecomment-15102441) two but it failed.
It would be nice if somebody who made it work could share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could split state definition across modules without defining an abstract state.
See [ng boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) for an example: [Module 1](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/master/src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.js) and [Module 2](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/master/src%2Fapp%2Fabout%2Fabout.js)

It wasn't working because of an undefined variable in a service that was injected to resolve function. That's why i didn't get any stack trace until i added logs to my codebase as mentioned by @Kasper:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.log('*******************');
    console.log('event', event.name);
    console.log('toState', toState.name);
    console.log('error', error);
    console.log('************');
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.log('*******************');
    console.log('event', event.name);
    console.log('toState', toState.name);
    console.log('fromState', fromState.name);
    console.error('error', error);
    console.log('************');
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.log('*******************');
    console.log('event', event.name);
    console.log('toState', toState.name);
    console.log('fromState', fromState.name);
    console.error('error', error);
    console.log('************');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `ui.router` to your module dependencies, it appears to be missing from your example.

If you want to unit test the modules in isolation, I would recommend you add the `ui.router` dependency explicitly to all of the modules utilising `$stateProvider`.

Comment: well, thanks for the advice :) but that didn't solve the problem: i can't transition between sub-modules states

Comment: Transitioning from `main.page1` to `main.page2` should work as `$state.go('^.page2')`, given that they share the same parent (as per the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#to)). Have you attempted transitioning straight from `page1` to `page2` without the reference to the parent? Do you have a stack trace to present?

Comment: And also - ensure that you **are** in fact on a sibling state if you call `.go(^.sibling)`. Could very well be the case of relative/absolute state differences that's crashing you - but I need to see more to be able to tell for certain.

Comment: i did try it, but it didn't work. Also, i don't get any errors

Comment: There's only so much I can do with that information. You'll need to show more implementation details, and/or blast your own codebase with logs and debugger statements to figure out what is going on. Not getting any errors could just as well be a silent fail on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $state to your $rootScope so that it can be accessible everywhere, try this:

```
yourApp.run([ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}]);
```

Hope this will help you!